# If only - can usage

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was wondering if this sentence is gramatically correct.

"If only skies like this can last longer"

Comment: I would switch "can" for "could" because it's subjunctive mood.

Comment: @probably_someone, I agree. Another option is **would**.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Requests for proofreading are explicitly off-topic, as they will not be of help to future visitors; we can assist if you identify a specific problem with grammar or usage that is bothering you, however. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a grammatically correct sentence, and not just because it's missing punctuation.

The sentence is expressing a kind of wish that is contrary to present facts or reality, so it's subjunctive and that makes it tricky, grammatically speaking.

The problem is that your clause, *...skies like this can last longer,* is in the indicative mood, so even though it is counterfactual, it is not subjunctive.

In subjunctive counterfactual and sentences expressing wishes, we use the  past tense form of the verb in the counterfactual clause (plural past for *be*), but it's not really past tense - it's the subjunctive mood. Like I said, it's tricky.

*If only skies like this lasted longer.*

You could also say, *...would last longer,* or *...could last longer,* but notice that *could* is the past tense of *can*, and *would* is the past tense of *will*.

There's a bit of controversy around the subjunctive in English, but it exists despite the complications of its current form. Here's a helpful link:
https://www.ceafinney.com/subjunctive/guide.html

Comment: @creampuff, Steve Lovell, probably_someone: please tag this with subjunctive-mood, I can't because I don't have enough rep points.